# How can I debug Tor connections to see where obfs4 fails?

Tags: bridge, obfs4

*Tor connects to private obfs4 bridge, but torbrowser fails*

I setup a private bridge (Tor 0.2.8.4) and tested it with Tor Browser (6.0.2) successfully.

When I enabled obsf4 (0.0.3) in the bridge, Tor Browser (both 6.0.2 and 6.5a1) fails connecting with a "general SOCKS server failure":

```
...
13/07/2016 15:07:46.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/07/2016 15:07:46.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
13/07/2016 15:07:47.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
13/07/2016 15:07:47.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
13/07/2016 15:07:47.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to x.x.x.x:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
13/07/2016 15:07:54.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
13/07/2016 15:07:54.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/07/2016 15:07:54.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

However, Tor connects well to the bridge via command line:

```
~# tor usebridges 1 bridge "obfs4 x.x.x.x:443 BRIDGEFINGERPRINT"
Jul 13 12:15:30.697 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2h and Zlib 1.2.8.
...
Jul 13 12:15:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
Jul 13 12:15:32.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'name' (fresh): $BRIDGEFINGERPRINT~name at x.x.x.x
...
Jul 13 12:15:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Jul 13 13:15:33.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'name' (fresh): $BRIDGEFINGERPRINT~name at x.x.x.x
Jul 13 14:15:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'name' (fresh): $BRIDGEFINGERPRINT~name at x.x.x.x
```

Moreover, when I configure torbrowser to connect to obfs4 bridges configured automatically, it works.

This is my bridge torrc:

```
ORPort 443
Address x.x.x.x
Nickname name
BridgeRelay 1
PublishServerDescriptor 0
SocksPort 0
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy managed
ExtORPort auto
```

I followed the <strike>[official documentation](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy-debian-instructions.html.en#instructions)</strike> in setting up the bridge. 
update: The [official obfs4proxy setup doc](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy) has moved to the wiki

Comment: Please delete obfs2 in the `ServerTransportPlugin` above. obfs4proxy does not support it and it may be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your `ClientTransportPlugin` or `ServerTransportPlugin` for obfs4proxy to include a `-logLevel` followed by one of `ERROR`,`WARN`,`INFO`, or `DEBUG`, an `-enableLogging=true` flag to enable logging, and a further `-unsafeLogging=true` flag which removed the address scrubbing. For example:

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy -enableLogging=true -logLevel INFO managed
Bridge obfs4 IP:Port Fingerprint Cert
UseBridges 1
```

This will log to a file located at `$TOR_PT_STATE_LOCATION/obfs4proxy.log`, which by default would be `pt_state/obfs4proxy.log` under your `DataDirectory`.

See: [obfs4proxy/main.go:315](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/tree/obfs4proxy/obfs4proxy.go#n315)

Comment: In the client, what file should I edit? Adding theClientTransportPlugin options at the end of the obfs4 line in  tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults makes Tor Browser crash (graciously). Same editing tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc

Comment: Added an example config that works for me, you should be editing the torrc-default existing `ClientTransportPlugin` line such that those options get added to the arguments passed to obfs4proxy

Comment: @canonizingironize I deleted the obfs2 entry in your posting. obfs4proxy does not support it and it's also not safe to use.

Comment: ACK, Jens. That line is copied verbatim (except for the path to obfs4proxy) from the Tor Browser torrc-defaults, would it be worth making a ticket to remove it from Tor Browser too if it's not safe?

Comment: Thank you C.I. and Jens. Logging obfs4proxy on Tor Browser showed that the connection was reset by the server. Logging on the server I found out my error: the PORT in the bridge line that you use with the client is the obfs4 port and not the Tor node port. BTW, -logLevel DEBUG blocks obfs4proxy from starting. I also corrected the docs link in my original question, as it was moved. Thanks!